# Доконать - от какого слова?

Tags: этимология

Есть такое разговорное слово "доконать", то есть, довести до какого-то критического состояния: *"Ты меня скоро доконаешь своими придирками!"* Но вот интересно, а какое происхождение этого слова? По идее, оно происходит от слова "кон", так? А кон - это то, на что кладут деньги в азартной игре. Хотя, возможно, у него есть еще какое-то значение.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, очень интересно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Доконать. Образовано с помощью приставки от конати – "кончать" и является производным от конъ – "начало". Та же основа присутствует и в слове конец.
krylov.academic.ru › Этимологический словарь русского языка. — СПб.: ООО "Виктория плюс"

Comment: Уточню значение глагола *конать* (по САР 1789-94 и Словарю 1847). "Доводить кого-либо до крайности" (до предела). Смысл чуть другой в отличие от "кончать".

Comment: Уж извините за мрачное сообщение. На Украине слово *"конати"* имеет более жуткое значение: 

умирать; кончаться; агонизировать; быть при последнем издыхания; отходить.

Основное значение - когда человек агонизирует, переходит от жизни к смерти.

укр. *сконав* = рус. *скончался*

Comment: Интересно, почему тогда "переконати" по-украински - "убедить".

Answer (score 0):

Слово «доконать» происходит от корня «КОНО», если слово «доКОНАть», выразить с помощью родственных или однокоренных слов, то оно означает: доКОНЪчить, приКОНЪчить, сГИНУть, довести до КОНЪца, до оКОНЪчания, до КОНЪчины. 
Ежели данное слово выразить с помощью равнозначных слов (синонимов), то «доконать» означает: уничтожить, довести до низа, до смерти, до убийства, до края, до крайности.

Comment: «...сГИНУть»? Может быть — скинуть? «...довести до низа»? В каком смысле?

Comment: Русский язык читается как с лево на право, так и с право на лево обратное прочтение, потому что русский язык слоговый язык, слога в корне слова при перестановки не меняют своё значение, может изменится только смысл. Корень в русском языке несёт значение слова. Слога в русском языке - приставки (префиксы), вставки (суффиксы), окончания (постфиксы)), могут употреблятся как перед корнем так и после него.

Comment: Странное у Вас представление о русском языке!

Answer (score 0):

Русский язык читается как с лево на право, так и с право на лево обратное прочтение, потому что русский язык слоговый язык, слога в корне слова при перестановки не меняют своё значение, может изменится только смысл. Корень в русском языке несёт значение слова. Слога в русском языке - приставки (префиксы), вставки (суффиксы), окончания (постфиксы)), могут употреблятся как перед корнем так и после него. Посему от корня "КОНО" (КОНЬ - верховое скачущие животное, КОНЕцъ, оКОНЕчие, оКОНЪчание, "КОНЁкъ=КОНЕцъ всему венец" в строительстве - верхнее горизонтальное ребро крыши, образованное пересечением двух кровельных скатов, из русского по-немецки ГЕНУкъ) / ГОНО / ГАНО (поГАНО, поГАНЫЙ, ГАНЬба, ГЪНОбить = плохой, дурной, позорный, пошлый, низкий, ничтожный) / ГИНО (съГИНУть) ≡ НОКО (НАКО / НАКЪ / НИК (съНИКАть, поНИКЪнуть) / НИЦЪ (упасть НИЦЪ)/ НИЧЪ (упасть НИЧЪком, уНИЧЪтожить, НИЧЪтожесътъво) / НИЗЪ (НИЗОсъть, уНИЗИть, НИЗЪкий) / НИЖЪ (уНИЖАть, съНИЖАться, НИЖЪний))

съНИКАть = поНИКЪнуть = съНИЗИться = съНИЖАться; 
поНИКЪший = НИЗЪкий = НИЖЪний; 
НИЗОсъть = НИЧЪтожъносъть = НИЧЪтожесътъво

съГИНУть = съКОНЪчаться = уНИЧЪтожиться ≡ уМЕРЕть ≡ поГИБЪнуть